# Cordova - Windows Phone 8, camera.getPicture + view image in <img /> tag?

Tags: html, image, cordova, windows-phone-8

I am not sure how to resolve externally obtained images (A.K.A via Camera/PhotoLibrary)

```
<img src="///myAppFolder/photoTaken.jpg" />
```

I did this on other platforms (Android + iPhone) by resolving the local-storage via window.requestFileSystem(); and appending the correct folder path (which looked much more absolute than what window phone provides - it only ever returns a relative path) and it works, however I am uncertain what to do in this case on the windows phone solution.

Using Cordova 2.5.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah! How silly of me, after mucking around for several hours then ending up posting I found the solution to my issue :) I was using **toURI()** when I shouldve been using **toURL()** after resolving. All turned out to be well!